# Laravel/Vue will not bind to data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel and want to create a simple edit application for editing a post. I am using Vue.js 2 to bind the data, but somehow it will not display it - and I am unsure what could be wrong.

When I display the data using Vue.js's e.g  of `@{{ postData.title }}` it displays the title on the page. But I want to display the data inside an input so that it can be edited.

The routing and everything is fine because I get the correct URL and I can display the data in Vue.js just not in the textboxes. Thanks in advance.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="postEdit">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
        <meta id="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <h1>Edit your post</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
           @{{ postData.title }}
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" v-model="postData.title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="post">Post</label>
          <textarea name="post" rows="8" cols="80" id="post" class="form-control" v-model="postData.post"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Post" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Vue.js:

```
var edit = new Vue({
  el: '#postEdit',
  data: {
    postData: <?php echo $post ?>,
  },

  methods: {

  },
});
```

My controller:

```
public function edit($id){
    $post = Post::find($id);
    return view('post.edit', compact('post'));
}
```

My Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\EloquentSoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'post', 'user_id'];
    protected $table = "posts";
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

My output when I run `edit.postData` in console:

```
Object { id: Getter & Setter, title: Getter & Setter, post: Getter & Setter, user_id: Getter & Setter, created_at: Getter & Setter, updated_at: Getter & Setter, deleted_at: Getter & Setter, … }
```

I am not sure how to fix this to get the correct data. I have used this method before and it always worked. I have never had the getter & setter show in my data so I am unsure how to handle this. Is the problem in my model, my database, the Vue.js, or the PHP?

Comment: Is your javascript file interpreted by PHP? This looks suspicious:     `postData: <?php echo $post ?>`. Are you sure this mix of php/javascript works right?

Comment: Hi, yes well that is how we do it at our company and we have used it many times. I myself have used this on other projects and it worked. Normally I would get the data, but it is the first time that data shows as "Getter & Setter", and  I'm not sure how or why this happens. I am still in training and learning.

Comment: *"Getter & Setter"* means that if you try to get `postData.id` then a function (getter) will be invoked to return you a computed value. Nothing to worry about - just enter `edit.postData.id` in the console to see the result. It's a shorthand for `postData.getId()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the post to an array when you echo it out.

```
postData: <?php echo $post->toArray(); ?>,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `postData: {!! json_encode($post) !!},` to get the encoded data.

Comment: Or use the `@json` directive in Laravel 5.4+